# How can I define a function using unkown number of variables?

Tags: scheme, racket, variadic-functions

I am studying Lisp for the first time and I was working on a simple function that append two lists. As I was testing the functualities of the predifined `append`, I noticed that I can give it more than two list and I wondered how to do it myself? So I wonder how to make a function in Lisp that take an unknown number of variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define function using dotted list for optional arguments. All optional arguments will be passed as a list to your function.

So for example this function takes one mandatory argument `a0` and any number of optional arguments passed as `a-rest` list:

```lisp
(define (take-many a0 . a-rest)
  a-rest)
```

Now, when you call it:

```lisp
(take-many 1 20 333)

=> (20 333)
```

you can see that optional second and thind argument are available as a list. To access them, you use standard list accessors like `car`, `cdr`, `nth` etc.

The same goes for `lambda`.

You can read more about it on [Dr Racket: 3.8 Procedure Expressions: lambda and lambda-case](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lambda.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._lambda%29%29) (look for `rest-id`).

Comment: thank you so much I'll be looking through the documentation that you mentioned

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`&rest`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_dac.htm)
[lambda list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_d.htm) keyword:

```lisp
(defun test-rest (a &rest b)
  (format t "1st argument: ~S; 2nd argument: ~S; other arguments: ~S~%"
          a (first b) (rest b)))
```

Now `(test-rest 1 2 3 4)` prints

> 1st argument: 1; 2nd argument: 2; other arguments: (3 4)

If you are interested specifically in Scheme, you can use use a dotted
arglist:

```lisp
(define (test-rest a . b) 
  (display (list (list "first" a) 
                 (list "others" b))))
```

Now `(test-rest 1 2 3 4)` will print

> ((first 1) (others (2 3 4)))

Comment: This is fine for CL, but what I understand OP was asking about Scheme like Lisp.